# Name tag for staff on science conference?

Tags: word-request

I am making name tags (badges) for international science conference. There are three category of participant:

1. Speakers - they will speak the reports.
2. Visitors - they will listen to the speakers.
3. Third category (I don't know how right it call) - they will to provide conference, to evaluate reports, to regulate discussion etc.

In my native language this is literally called **Organising Committee.** But I want to do badges that will meet to standards of english language.
**The question:** How properly to call third category of participants? To my mind - if them call like staff, then it will be insulting for professors and other important persons who will be in the comission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Organizing Committee Member*** would be perfectly acceptable in English. However, long titles are not often used on name tags/badges, so you might want to shorten it to ***Organizer***, or perhaps ***Moderator***. Sometimes, this role may be referred to as ***Referee***, but I've encountered objections to that because conferences are not sporting events.

As @JayA.Little notes in the comments, ***Coordinator*** is also a valid possibility.

***Staff*** is not insulting or demeaning, unless you're thinking of confusion with the people who manage the facility (e.g., the people you talk to when a lightbulb is out).

Comment: Agreed, you can also add "Coordinator".

Comment: That's a silly reason to object to _referee_. That said, I'd still avoid the term _referee_, because (a) it's not a good catch-all term, and (b) that word has a rather [specific meaning](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+refereed+journal) in the scientific community.

Comment: @J.R. - I don't disagree; I merely note that it has happened.